# Combining query outputs to make one summary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q1 outputs

```
DogCnt
101
```

Q2 outputs

```
CatCnt
6
```

Q3 outputs

```
BirdCnt
21
```

How can I combine both query outputs in to generate this output?

```
Animal  Cnt
Dog     101
Cat       6
Bird     21
```

Comment: What are the 3 queries you *actually* have? *How* you combine them depends on the queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Animal = 'Dog', Cnt = DogCnt FROM (<Q1>) AS Q1
UNION ALL
SELECT Animal = 'Cat', CatCnt FROM (<Q2>) AS Q2
UNION ALL
SELECT Animal = 'Bird', BirdCnt FROM (<Q3>) AS Q3;
```

But if all these source queries are originally coming from the same table, there is absolutely a more efficient way to do that (for specifics you'll need to provide more specifics, like what is the table structure and how are you getting those counts).

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `CTE`s :

```
;WITH Q1 (
    <query here>
), Q2 (
    <query here>
), Q3 (
    <query here>
)

select 'dog' as animal, DogCnt
from q1 
union all
select 'Cat' as animal, CatCnt
from q2
union all
select 'Bird' as animal, BirdCnt
from q3;
```